# Why does Ctrl+Arrow make my terminal switch to a strange mode?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard, gnome-terminal

When i type Ctrl+Left or Ctrl+Right within `Guake` or `gnome-terminal` the last one's behaviour turns to a some kind of non-usual mode: `-` key acts like `arrow up` and `+` like `arrow down`, `v` runs Nano, etc. How can i disable this *feature* ?

**UPD:** my friend told me that's X.org hotkeys... How can i disable 'em? Googling does not help at all...

**UPD2**: [here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTUsYNILsAU) a video showing what's going on.

Comment: Probably something with your settings. I don't have that behavior, neither for guake nor gnome-terminal.

Comment: Sounds pretty much like how emacs/vi work... completely intuitive. :-)

Comment: Does this happen in another account with your distribution's default settings? If you press `Ctrl+V` then `Ctrl+Left` at a shell prompt, does this insert characters (if so, which) or not?

Comment: Ctrl+v and then Ctrl+left inserts `^[[1;5C`.

Comment: And yes, this issue is present for another account.

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you run Xterm instead of Gnome-terminal? What if you run zsh instead of bash (type `exec zsh` at the bash prompt; install `xterm` and `zsh` first if needed)? If the problem is specific to bash, please post `/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc`, there's probably a bad binding there.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks a lot! At last, the problem is solved! The `$if mode=emacs ... $endif` construction failed all the stuff (the mode was set in line `set editing-mode vi` above that `if`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was pretty elegant and simple: editing `/etc/inputrc` and disabling `vi mode`.

Here's the renewed `inputrc` file:

```
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

#set editing-mode vi

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
#$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

#$endif
```

Should read more 'bout that modes. Thanks everybody for the trouble-taking!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. My `/etc/inputrc` was configured correctly, but due to some strange reason I had skeleton configuration in `~/.inputrc` which then disabled all the mappings in `/etc/inputrc`.

So, my solution was:

```
rm ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: I had a strange, empty ~/.inputrc file. After I deleted it, as you said, I opened a new shell, and it was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianPeterson same here! I wonder why .inputrc overwrites /etc/inputrc.Maybe it is meant to be an easy way to saying "I want to start from a clean plate"? anyway, you can still keep the .inputrc file and add `$include  /etc/inputrc` as first line. This will allow you to keep the defaults and modify some if it.

Answer (score 1):

According to `nano's` title bar, you are editing a bash history file after you press <kbd>v</kbd>:

`/tmp/bash-fc-1212173730`

I suspect that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> are activating the interactive history mode.

Does your `.bashrc` contain bindings for `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward`?

You can disable this behaviour by commenting out, or removing, any of those bind lines in your `.bashrc` or in `.bash_aliases`.